# Is it safe to use format parameter as additional argument in sscanf?

Tags: c, collision, stdio

Is the following code safe to use? I mean if the pattern might be scanned and overwriten in one loop, or if such collision never occurs, or if it is implementation dependent.

```
char pattern[32] = "%31s";
sscanf("hello",pattern,pattern);
```

I didn't find any note about that [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/?kw=sscanf) nor [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf).

(Use case: sometimes I use `pattern` as temporary buffer.)

Comment: No it's not safe. If you have a compile-time fixed format string then use it directly in your [`scanf` (and family)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) call, and definitely don't use the same buffer as both the format string and destination.

Comment: Your first parameter doesn't contain any conversions (remember, **only** the first parameter is the format string), so this is "safe", it just won't do anything except consuming "hello" from stdin if it is there.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude misread it ... ok, totally unsafe. btw, question title is wrong then

Comment: @FelixPalmen If this is safe, how about extending it? Like `char pattern[32] = "%5s %d";
sscanf("hey 32",pattern,pattern, &someInt);`?

Comment: Side note: sscanf("hello",pattern,pattern);  This will overwrite `pattern`.  Isn't the third argument supposed to be a different variable name?

Comment: @SouravGhosh the question title says `scanf` and I didn't look close enough at the code, just forget it ...

Comment: @Nguaial You're right, but I guess OP is asking _if_ we can use the same..

Comment: @SouravGhosh - Yup.  That is the question.  Thanks. (00)

Comment: One hint of this being UB is the function prototype: `int sscanf(const char * restrict s, const char * restrict format, ...);`. Parameter `format` is qualified with `restrict`, limiting all access to this pointer.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading typo in the title.

Comment: Don't do weird things, just because you _can_. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh se the use case at the end of the question. It could be useful to save memory if the format is long and in many different instances. Alas it is undefined behaviour as Jonathan explained us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) covers this. It says:

> #### 7.21.6.7 The `sscanf` function
>
> ```
> int sscanf(const char * restrict s, const char * restrict format, ...);
> ```

The `restrict` means that the format can't be the same as any of the arguments.

The description says:

> If copying
> takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

What you're trying to do is 'undefined behaviour'.  Don't do that.

Comment: Perfect answer - I haven't met `restrict` before. Thanks.

Comment: Sir, `If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.`...isn't this with reference to the "source" and "destination"? How does that involve the format string, exactly?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: The complete paragraph is: _The `sscanf` function is equivalent to `fscanf`, except that input is obtained from a
string (specified by the argument `s`) rather than from a stream. Reaching the end of the
string is equivalent to encountering end-of-file for the `fscanf` function. If copying
takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined._  The objects that could overlap are `s`, `format`, and any of the arguments in the `...` section of the call.  The ban on overlapping copies covers them all, I believe.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ You're allowed to do something like: `if (sscanf(source, "%s %s %s", target, target, target) != 3) …` — it's one way of getting the third word, but `if (sscanf(source, "%*s %*s %s", target) == 1) …` would do the job more cleanly.  The assignments to the `target` are done sequentially.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler exactly....I was trying to understand...in the whole process, where the "copying" action fits? the process is , read the input, match with format specifier, if match, write to argument which has not received the result of conversion, right? So, copying.....is from source to destination....right? Not between the format string and destination..

Comment: Yes, copying is from source to destination, with the caveat the code in the question seems to be treating the format string as one of the destinations too, so there is copying to overlapping objects.

Comment: As a sidenote sir, the `restrict` says it all. I'm just trying to get my concepts clear about the language used in the spec, that's all, and thanks for your time. :)

Comment: Sir, sorry if i'm missing something obvious, but how the copying is overlapping, the source is the string literal and the destination is the `pattern` array. How the copying is overlapping?

Comment: In the question, first example, you have: `sscanf("hello", pattern, pattern);`.  The role of `format` is played by the same variable that is receiving the scanned text — `pattern`.  That's the no-no that `restrict` says is not allowed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Right, that's the very point and __the__ answer, but since you mentioned the overlapping as part of your answer, i'm just trying to link these two things. In this case, do we actually hit the overlapping issue?

Comment: FWIW, in [my previous comment under question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44150988/is-it-safe-to-use-format-parameter-as-additional-argument-in-sscanf/44151443?noredirect=1#comment75319237_44150988), there's a scenario wher overlapping makes sens, but what about this specifiec case, sir?

Comment: Very much so.  Empirically, you might get away with it this time, but it's not a good idea to rely on that.  The standard says it is undefined behaviour, so don't play with fire.